# Can an iPhone 6s Plus battery be recharged after going real dead

Tags: battery, charging, iphone

I just bought a new iPhone 6 four days ago and hardly used except to browse first page, never paid attention to the battery until really dead.

Can an iPhone 6s Plus battery be recharged?
Ive been trying recharging both from the plug and laptop and still no sign of power on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iPhone batteries *normally* can be charged after going dead (especially after only a few days). It can often take several minutes before coming on.

Since your phone hasn't come on yet, it could indicate a hardware problem and you should take it to an authorized Apple store.